# Transaction not in progress, cannot be used in API requests. FIRESTORE ERROR

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I am learning transactions on firestore and I making some modifications to the sample functions of documentation but I'm not sure why I get "Transaction not in progress..." when I make transactions without a function

```
transaction = firestore_db.transaction()
doc_ref = firestore_db.collection(u'metadata').document(u'projects')

#@firestore.transactional
snapshot = doc_ref.get(transaction=transaction)
transaction.update(doc_ref, {
    u'count': snapshot.get(u'count') + 1
})

# [END update_data_transaction]
```

What is the meaning of that error? I want to make a counter of my projects in order to paginate it on my wep app I would like the user can move between the different pages and not just prev and next as the documentation show. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @blink_182 I believe this way that you are trying to get the size and updating your counter it's not the best option. I would recommend you to check these two following tutorials for pagination in Firestore: [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-firestore/firestore-pagination/) and [here](https://morioh.com/p/b287c3c0ee1f) - this one not in Python, but the logic is valid for Python as well.

Comment: Thank you @gso_gabriel yeah prev and next is the most suitable solution that firestore gives you but the owner of the page want to move between different pages from 4 to 8 and so on. The solution that gives me the second page with an aggregate cloud function just count the number of documents but I don't get anything about the cursors to make "the slicing" of the documents depending on the page chosen by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function, or better to say the decorator `@firestore.transactional` was an essential part of the logic. The error message means you didn't start the transaction, you've just instantiated a trnsaction object.

You could begin the transaction manually using `transaction._begin`, but I'd strangly suggest against it. Just use the decorater which provides simple way to manage transactions, including for example error handling.

Comment: Thank you very much @Trilliput!