# Firebase Python admin sdk - Transaction not in progress, cannot be used in API requests

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing the above error. This error only comes If I my code is deployed as cloud function.
I am not using transactional decorator

My scenario is 
Function1()---transaction=db.transaction --->Function2(transaction)--does some things----function3(transaction)

And then Function1 commits the transaction. It used to work, but suddenly its not working.
Can someone please guide me, how can I implement this using python.

I am unable to find any example - which shows the example of transaction._begin and transaction.commit

Comment: This issue may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493125/transaction-not-in-progress-cannot-be-used-in-api-requests-firestore-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction not in progress, cannot be used in API requests. FIRESTORE ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493125/transaction-not-in-progress-cannot-be-used-in-api-requests-firestore-error)